# how to find rows with both positive and negative values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
     e_col   in_col     word_col      w_col
     31      9        algorithm    -0.053538
     31      9              ubc    -0.053578
     31      9              kth    -0.053595
     31      8              ubc    -0.053633
     30      8        algorithm     0.043637
     30      7             dale     0.053648
     28      6             dale     0.053671
```

I want to find the rows in which the same `word_col` got both positive and negative values in `w_col`.

So, For example here the output will be:

```
 31      9        algorithm    -0.053538
 30      8        algorithm     0.043637
```

Comment: maybe you could `groupby(['word_col'])` and then check every group separatelly. If group has `group['w_col'] >= 0`  and `group['w_col'] < 0` then you have your rows.

Comment: Thanks for following @furas, I tried various version of `print(df.groupby('word').apply([(df['w_col']<0) & (df['w_col']>0)]))` but either raises error or not my expected output.

Comment: if you tried this then put this information in question and add full error message. If you create minimal working code which we could copy and run then maybe someone will create solution.

Comment: I was trying to update with the most sophisticated thing I did which received the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit 2**: you may also use `transform` to avoid `set_index/reset_index` as follows:

```
m = df.w_col.lt(0).groupby(df.word_col).transform('nunique').eq(2)
df.loc[m]

Out[2768]:
   e_col  in_col   word_col     w_col
0     31       9  algorithm -0.053538
4     30       8  algorithm  0.043637
```

---

**Edit 1**: a shorter way to create `m` is using `nunique()` as follows:

```
m =  df.w_col.lt(0).groupby(df.word_col).nunique().eq(2)
```

**Original**:
Do the following: create boolean mask on `w_col` less than `0` and `groupby` it by `word_col`. Next, call `unique` on each group and find any group having `len` = 2. Use this as the mask to indexing on `df.set_index` and `reset_index` back.

```
m = df.w_col.lt(0).groupby(df.word_col).unique().str.len().eq(2)
df.set_index('word_col').loc[m].reset_index()

Out[2738]:
    word_col  e_col  in_col     w_col
0  algorithm     31       9 -0.053538
1  algorithm     30       8  0.043637
```